# How to open Apple Maps using Flutter/Dart?

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, mapkit

Our Flutter App shows a number of locations using Google Maps, if available, or else using the local browser.

Although we had already previously uploaded a binary code for iOS which was accepted by Apple and successfully published in the App Store, now that we have added some more locations and thus attempted to publish a new version, **Apple has rejected our binary**, stating that it is mandatory to use **"Apple Maps"** instead of anything that starts with a *"G"*, like *Google*...

The rejection message reads as follows:

> > **Your app's location feature is not integrated with the built-in mapping functionality, which limits users to a third-party maps app.**
> >
> > **Next Steps**
> >
> > **To resolve this issue, please revise your app to give users the option to launch the native Apple Maps app.**

I have found that there exists some documentation about a Javascript library named *MapKit JS*, which serves precisely the purpose of interacting with **Apple Maps**: **https://developer.apple.com/maps/mapkitjs/**

```
<script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>

<script>
        mapkit.init({
            authorizationCallback: function(done) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", "/services/jwt");
                xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
                    done(this.responseText);
                });
                xhr.send();
            }
        });

        var Cupertino = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
            new mapkit.Coordinate(37.3316850890998, -122.030067374026),
            new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(0.167647972, 0.354985255)
        );
        var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
        map.region = Cupertino;
        </script>
```

Nevertheless, I could really use some help no how to connect with this *MapKit JS* using **DART**, instead of JAVA, for our **Flutter application**.

**Thank you immensely for your kind help!**

Daniel

Comment: Interesting, AppStore full of apps that use Google Maps

Comment: even more interestingly, this very same App was already approved and published less than one month ago... it is only now that we have added a few more locations, that Apple has suddenly decided that we must use Apple Maps instead of Google Maps...

the truth of it is that our updated has been rejected...

Comment: to justify their rejection, so they say:

Your app's location feature is not integrated with the built-in mapping functionality, which limits users to a third-party maps app.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to give users the option to launch the native Apple Maps app.

Comment: @CostaRica, what do you mean when you say that the problem arose when you _have added some more locations_ ?

Comment: hello, thanks for asking...

I am not suggesting that there existed some technical connection or consequence from adding more locations... What I was trying to say is the contrary, that the sudden rejection to our update from Apple was arbitrary, because they hadn't protested nor said anything about it before... 

I mention that we added more places, using the very same logic, because this is exactly what we did, and this was the only difference between the first version which was accepted, and the second which was rejected... it just means there was more data, more Google places...

Comment: in any case, what we did to solve the problem was that we simply changed the URL to Apple Maps, like this: url = "https://maps.apple.com/?q=IPHE&ll=9.0067418,-79.5300556&z=16", instead of using the Google Maps URL's...

Comment: and, although we haven't implemented it yet, we are planning to offer both options on a future version of the App, because in our opinion the user experience is much better with Google Maps than with Apple Maps... I do not believe that Apple would reject a new version that offers both options, because that was literally what they requested, that there existed an option available to use Apple Maps... for the moment, we simply replaced all the URL's to Apple Maps, because this was a much simpler solution and we were in quite a hurry to have the new version of the App published on the App Store.

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, install the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin

Secondly, add the below code in Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Thirdly:

```
var urlAppleMaps = 'https://maps.apple.com/?q=$lat,$lng';

if (await canLaunch(urlAppleMaps)) {
  await launch(urlAppleMaps);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

We can use it like this:

```dart
 _launchMap(BuildContext context, lat, lng) async {
    var url = '';
    var urlAppleMaps = '';
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${lat},${lng}";
    } else {
      urlAppleMaps = 'https://maps.apple.com/?q=$lat,$lng';
      url = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=$lat,$lng&directionsmode=driving";
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else if (await canLaunch(urlAppleMaps)) {
      await launch(urlAppleMaps);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
 }
```

Comment: what about this code on android? will this code launch google maps or will launch the browser?

Comment: Thanks. I saw I can avoid to edit the Info.plist file. Is that edit mandatory?

Answer (score 7):

You could try to use a [Map Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher) plugin to launch apple/google maps depending on a platform

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:map_launcher/map_launcher.dart';

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  await MapLauncher.launchMap(
    mapType: MapType.apple,
    coords: Coords(31.233568, 121.505504),
    title: "Shanghai Tower",
    description: "Asia's tallest building",
  );
} else {
  await MapLauncher.launchMap(
    mapType: MapType.google,
    coords: Coords(31.233568, 121.505504),
    title: "Shanghai Tower",
    description: "Asia's tallest building",
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea but maybe you can try to use the [url_launch plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) to launch a url following the schemata given in the apple maps url schemata given here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I have found is to replace the google maps URL with a maps.apple.com equivalent, using the same url_launcher function.

For example, the original function for Google Maps:

```
void _mapaBethania() async {
    const url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Panamanian+Institute+for+Special+Training/@9.0067418,-79.5300556,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8faca84549395297:0x9c54b1fdb96ac590!8m2!3d9.0067365!4d-79.5278669";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Lo sentimos, no es posible abrir: $url';
    }
  }
```

Has become:

```
void _mapaBethania() async {
  const url = "https://maps.apple.com/?q=IPHE&ll=9.0067418,-79.5300556&z=16";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Lo sentimos, no es posible abrir: $url';
    }
  }
```

Nevertheless, although this change does fulfill Apple's enforced obligation to use their own software instead of the competition's, the user experience with Apple Maps is very poor, because once the Map App is shown, it becomes a bit confusing and difficult to return back to the original App.

Therefore, I am planning to write code that enables both options, Apple Maps in order to comply with Apple enforcement, and also Google Maps in order to provide a better user experience, despite Apple.

Anyway, the latter is just a personal opinion; the true fact is that replacing the URL for a maps.apple.com equivalent using the same launch_url function, does seem acceptable to comply with Apple requirements.